# Return empty object if the condition is met after loading Typeorm

Tags: node.js, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

I have the following code, I would like that if the condition is met it returns an empty object. I could not put as a condition in finding because I want it to be applied automatically in each entity that I have.

This object is deactivated and I want that instead of returning the object it returns an empty object when the function after loading has been executed

```
await this.Repository.find({where: {id: 4}}) // This Object Entity Is Disabled 

import { EventSubscriber, EntitySubscriberInterface } from 'typeorm';

@EventSubscriber()
export class BaseSubscriber implements EntitySubscriberInterface {

async afterLoad(entity) {
        if (entity.disabled){
            return {} //?
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO, first of all,  I recommend you if you are not sure about all the entities that have `disabled`  to make for each single entity a specific subscriber.

For your problem, you can do a trick to return an empty object by deleting the props:
***here's an example with a specific entity subscriber:***

```
    @EventSubscriber()
export class UserSubscriber implements EntitySubscriberInterface<User> {

    
    listenTo() {
        return User;
    }

    /**
     * Called after entity is loaded.
     */
    afterLoad(entity: User) {
       
        if(entity.disabled) {
            for (const prop of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(entity)) {
                delete entity[prop];
              }
        }        
    }

}
```

Comment: This is great and works when returning the empty object, but I thought that returning the empty object would not add it to the results list, here is an example for my Customer entity
Query result when searching for all customers = [Client {id: 1 ....}, Client {id: 3 ....}, Client {}]
How can I prevent it from being added to the results list if it is disabled?

Comment: your question was clear which is to return an empty object, for the current question why you wouldn't add it to the query `await this.Repository.find({where: {id: 4,disabled:true}})` it'll gives you the result wanted